# Confused about AMD/Intel

Tags: ati

When I go to the downloads page to get Ubuntu, it automatically downloads the AMD version, but my computer has no hardware with AMD on it. I only have Intel and Nvidia. Also, when I install this AMD version on my computer, it works (other than the constant random freezing of the computer when I use Ubuntu). I don't really understand why the amd version works on a computer with an intel processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the name of the processor architecture: "amd64" with the brand of processor.

Current Intel processors run the "amd64" processor architecture. The architecture is named that because it was initially invented by AMD (or at least, the 64-bit extensions were).

The correct architecture for your CPU is "amd64".  Sometimes this architecture is called "x86_64" - this is synonymous.