Ubuntu Server Download
It appears that the download is based on local laptop, however it says AMD in the title (Laptop is amd) however the chip of the server is intel.
where can I find the intel download?  or will this amd one work ?

The binaries for AMD64 will also work on processors that implement the Intel 64 architecture (formerly EM64T), i.e. the architecture that Microsoft calls x64, and AMD called x86-64 before calling it AMD64. They will not work on Intel Itanium Processors (formerly IA-64).
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64 &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/641112/confused-about-amd-intel

This question is similar to: Is the 64-Bit version of Ubuntu only compatible with AMD CPUs?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
